# Comparing similar xml files with XmlUnit with unordered tags (same tag name with different attributes)

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I am trying successfully XmlUnit, and is very helpful in my job. Now, I have a little problem, that I don't know how to solve. I have a java class, that has a Set, and when transforming it into XML, the elements inside can have any order.

When I try these two files in XmlUnit it works (Diff says that they are similar):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Monitor>
    <AvailableMeasures>
        <MeasureDescriptorA name="netInput_mynetwork"></MeasureDescriptorA>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_myothernetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
    </AvailableMeasures>
</Monitor>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Monitor>
    <AvailableMeasures>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_myothernetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
        <MeasureDescriptorA name="netInput_mynetwork"></MeasureDescriptorA>
    </AvailableMeasures>
</Monitor>
```

But when the tags have the same name (with different attributes) it doesn't work (it mixes the attributes, and expect the one in the other tag):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Monitor>
    <AvailableMeasures>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_myothernetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_mynetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
    </AvailableMeasures>
</Monitor>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Monitor>
    <AvailableMeasures>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_mynetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
        <MeasureDescriptor name="netInput_myothernetwork"></MeasureDescriptor>
    </AvailableMeasures>
</Monitor>
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I found the solution by myself, with this piece of code:

  Diff diff = new Diff(controlXml, responseXml);
  diff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());

it is done ;)

Comment: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, I thought I couldn't answer my own question. I will answer myself now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

```
Diff diff = new Diff(controlXml, responseXml);
diff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for XMLUnit 2.0:

```
    Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(expected))
            .withTest(Input.fromString(actual))
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes))
            .checkForSimilar()
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution only works with attributes order but it will not work if you have issues with the same element type order like below:

```
    <CustomerDataSet>
        <CustomerData>
            <Key>ACCOUNT_TYPE</Key>
            <Value>GREEN</Value>
        </CustomerData>
        <CustomerData name = "bla">
            <Key>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Key>
            <Value>MVNO_Automation_8@test.fr</Value>
        </CustomerData>
        <CustomerData>
            <Key>DATE_OF_BRITH</Key>
            <Value>01-01-1976</Value>
        </CustomerData>
    </CustomerDataSet>

            <CustomerDataSet>
        <CustomerData name = "bla">
            <Key>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Key>
            <Value>MVNO_Automation_8@test.fr</Value>
        </CustomerData>
        <CustomerData>
            <Key>ACCOUNT_TYPE</Key>
            <Value>GREEN</Value>
        </CustomerData>
        <CustomerData>
            <Key>DATE_OF_BRITH</Key>
            <Value>01-01-1976</Value>
        </CustomerData>
    </CustomerDataSet>
```

However, you can work around this by using `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` instead.