# comparing two xmls using xmlunit ignorng their order

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have two xml files which I need to compare using xmlunit

content of these xml files are always same except their order

ex:

```
 <report>
     <component name = "a">
         <component name = "b"/>
         <component name = "c"/>
     </component>
</report>
```

Here the order of the inside component may be different like below

```
<report>
     <component name = "a">
         <component name = "c"/>
         <component name = "b"/>
     </component>
</report>
```

When I compare these two xml I want diff.similar() to be true.

What I tried so far is

```
try(FileInputStream fileStream1 = new FileInputStream(expXMLPath)) {
        try(FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream(genXMLPath)) {
            InputSource inputSource1 = new InputSource(fileStream1);
            InputSource inputSource2 = new InputSource(fileStream2);
            diff = new Diff(inputSource1, inputSource2);
            RegDiffListener ignorableElementsListener = new RegDiffListener(
                    ignorableXPathsRegex);
            diff.overrideDifferenceListener(ignorableElementsListener);
            diff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
            diff.overrideElementQualifier(new MultiLevelElementNameAndTextQualifier(1, true));
            diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());
            // diff.overrideElementQualifier(new
            // ElementNameAndTextQualifier());
            return diff;
        }
```

I tried with different option of overrideElementQualifier and nothing is working. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580518/comparing-similar-xml-files-with-xmlunit-with-unordered-tags-same-tag-name-with are you sure the problem is the leading space in your first sample?

Comment: yes I am sure. It is not the reason. I am using  XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true); and XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true); and I am getting a message which says  it was expecting b but found c

Comment: Did any solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution mentioned by [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc) XMLUnit treat the documents as `similar`.

If you want them to be treated as `identical` one solution could be to implement an [DifferenceListener](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/DifferenceListener.html) which ignores attribute differences at those nodes. Finde below a snippet for demonstration.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DifferenceConstants;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DifferenceListener;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class IgnoreOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {
        try (FileInputStream fileStream1 = new FileInputStream("file1.xml");
                FileInputStream fileStream2 = new FileInputStream("file2.xml")) {
            InputSource inputSource1 = new InputSource(fileStream1);
            InputSource inputSource2 = new InputSource(fileStream2);
            Diff diff = new Diff(inputSource1, inputSource2);
            // to treat the files as identical
            diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreAttributeDifference());
            // to treat the files as similar
            // diff.overrideElementQualifier(
            //     new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
            System.out.println("identical: " + diff.identical());
            System.out.println("similar  : " + diff.similar());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ignores attribute differences on node
     * "/report[\d+]/component[\d+]/component[\d+]/@name"
     */
    private static class IgnoreAttributeDifference 
        implements DifferenceListener {

        @Override
        public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
            String xpathPattern = 
               "/report\\[\\d+\\]/component\\[\\d+\\]/component\\[\\d+\\]/@name";
            String controlXpath = difference.getControlNodeDetail()
                .getXpathLocation();
            String testXpath = difference.getTestNodeDetail()
                .getXpathLocation();
            if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ATTR_VALUE_ID
                    && controlXpath.matches(xpathPattern)
                    && testXpath.matches(xpathPattern)) {
                return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
            } else {
                return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void skippedComparison(Node node, Node node1) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

output using `diff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier())`

```
identical: false
similar  : true
```

output using `diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreAttributeDifference())`

```
identical: true
similar  : true
```