# XML Unit testing: XmlUnit alternatives for .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, unit-testing

I'm looking for XmlUnit alternatives, since:

- XmlUnit looks like a dead project: "The current release is XmlUnit .Net 0.4, April 2009";
- *"Please be aware that the .Net code base is not as advanced as its Java counterpart, in particular there is currently no explicit support for namespaces."* (that says it all)
- It's bugged [Are there any alternatives to XmlUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727299/are-there-any-alternatives-to-xmlunit)
- I don't really like its static configuration: [Are there any alternatives to XmlUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727299/are-there-any-alternatives-to-xmlunit/6028170#6028170)

How do you test your xml serialization/deserialization?

PS: More details:

- I'm using NUnit
- I'm stuck with .NET 2

Answer (score 2):

I read that you look for a purely NUnit-based solution, but I think it's worth to mention that **[Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org)** provides [several interesting assertions](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2010/04/xml-assertions-in-mbunit-v3.html) for testing XML. More information and examples on the [Gallio wiki](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3axml_assertions).

```
Assert.Xml.AreEqual(
  "<value x='123' y='456'/>", 
  "<VALUE y='456' x='123'></VALUE>", 
  XmlOptions.Loose); // Pass!
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using NUnit. But MbUnit's xml assertions seem interesting. For now I'm using Microsoft Xml Diff & Patch's dll, but perhaps I'll reference MbUnit dlls someday... thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you but maybe you should not accept my answer. First it's not for NUnit. But more important, it does not help in getting more answers from other people (just my opinion)